# Can't open serial port on Matlab UNIX

Tags: c++, matlab, serial-port

I'm trying to establsih serial communication with an Arduino through USB (running Arch Linux). I can do it in a straightforward way trough a C++ program and using `boost::asio`, but recently I installed Matlab and been encoutering some issues. I manage to create the serial object with `s0=serial('/dev/ttyACM0')` but when I call `fopen(s0)` I get the following error:

```
Error using serial/fopen (line 72)
Open failed: Port: /dev/ttyACM0 is not available. No ports are available.
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did to get serial port communication work in Matlab R2014a on Arch Linux 64 bit:

1a) follow the steps described here: http://www.matlabarduino.org/serial-communication.html:

> sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0
>   Alternatively, add your user to the group uucp: > sudo gpasswd --add username uucp
>
> sudo nano $MATLABROOT/bin/$ARCH/java.opts --> add: -Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts=/dev/ttyS0:/dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyACM0

1b) check that the connection works in gtkterm (select port ttyACM0)

2) additionally (critical only for Matlab):

> sudo chmod 777 /run/lock 
>   /run/lock was symlinked from /var/lock on my distro, so you might have to do this with the latter dir (was 755); alternatively, you can manage access rights to /run/lock/ by ACL.

How I got to this solution:

> sudo strace -p 4668 -f -s100 2>&1 | grep -C3 --color -i -e /dev -e serialports -e uucp
>   -p: process ID == second column from > sudo ps -aux | grep -i matlab
>   Then, in Matlab type >> sps=instrhwinfo('serial') (which in my case always returned a structure of empty cell-arrays) and monitor the output of strace.

Hope that helps!
cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, only root can use the serial port.

And you can add your id to the serial group "dialout", so you can use the serial port.

Comment: But it worked for the OP in the C++ program. Presumably, joaocandre used the same access rights.

Comment: I've tried calling matlab with root (`sudo matlab`), but I get the same error. I've also tried to change the read/write permissions of the serial port as suggested in http://www.matlabarduino.org/serial-communication.html but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Just make soft link from /dev/ttyACM0 to /dev/ttyS[0-255].

```
   ln -sf /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/ttyS100 # for example
```

Below Matlab R2017a may face this issue.

Detailed Description can find here:

[Why is my serial port not recognized with MATLAB on Linux or Solaris?](https://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95024-why-is-my-serial-port-not-recognized-with-matlab-on-linux-or-solaris)

Hope this can be helped.